# how to write a function that takes a list of strings, and returns a list with the strings in sorted order

Tags: python, string, sorting

write a function that takes a list of strings, and returns a list with the strings in sorted order,except that it groups all the strings that begin with 'x' first.

For instance,
['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark'] yields
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']

I am thinking that this can be done by making two lists and sorting each of them before combining them but I got nothing.

any idea would be helpfull

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @DSM yes, very possible!

Answer (score 4):

Splitting the list is a good idea, you could do this using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
xs = [s for s in l if s[0] == "x"] # or 'if s.startswith("x")'
no_xs = [s for s in l if s[0] != "x"] # or 'if not s.startswith("x")'
```

You can then apply `sorted()` to each list and add them back together:

```
sorted(xs) + sorted(no_xs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Used the `sorted()` bif with a custom key.

```
KEY = 'X0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ'
sorted(my_list, key=KEY.index)
```

Comment: Note that this solution also changes the notion of sortedness for characters other than the first; this may not be desirable.

Comment: This is a good start, but how will it sort `['xa', 'xx']`? I believe 'x' is only special if it is the first character of the string.

Comment: This is a `SyntaxError` (too many closing parentheses) then a `ValueError: substring not found`, as lower case characters aren't included!

Comment: Aside from the first-character aspect, this won't sort the OP's example because of the case differences.